# Python Linux Debugging in Eclipse (Indego 3.8 + Ubuntu 17)

Tags: pydev

I'm trying to setup the Python 2.7 Eclipse debugger on a fresh install of Ubuntu Linux 17.

For some reason it doesn't show up in the tool chain even after installing python in eclipse?

[image: Install]

[image: Preferences]

This is a fresh install of Eclipse on Ubuntu 17 and python seems to be working from the command line however, I did notice that pydb wasn't installed if that is required?

My error logs say this...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2017-12-28 22:49:15.104
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 10050 2017-12-28 22:49:15.104
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 10005 2017-12-28 22:49:15.104
!MESSAGE "PyDev for Eclipse" will be ignored because it is already installed.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 10005 2017-12-28 22:49:15.104
!MESSAGE "PyDev for Eclipse Developer Resources" will be ignored because it is already installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of settings that make it difficult to install eclipse as root user.

[image: Install]

[image: pydev]

It maybe that the problem has to do with the Ubuntu Software Center not working good with the old version of Eclipse which it tries to install (Eclipse 3.8 and PyDev).  The other point is one maybe needs to install PyDev as root user if you install it through the software center?  **For some reason PyDev wasn't able to find the correct version to install or that there was a root/local user conflict problem during install.**  So I just installed everything manually and it worked using the latest version of Eclipse rather then the Ubuntu Software Center configuration.

There maybe is a way to install it as root using the software center?

Answer (score 1):

The usual culprit is having an old java vm there.

Make sure you take a look at http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html to help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Java does say its installed... $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you said you're in Eclipse 3.8. For that, you need an old PyDev version as well (http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html has the requisites and info if you really need an older Eclipse version).

Comment: Thanks!  It must have been a combination.  However, the pydev website recommended the version to install not me.  So it maybe that I still need to use the newer version.  A lot of people are having problems with this install on Ubuntu Software Center.  I'm not sure if anyone in the world has it working yet with the Software Center + Eclipse + Python??!!?  However, the Oxygen PyDev install works on Ubuntu with the debugger, I've tested this however, I had to install it as local user not root.  There maybe a lot of settings to get it working properly for all users?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how exactly the Ubuntu Software Center should be used with Eclipse/PyDev myself. My suggestion is getting Eclipse from Eclipse.org as the PyDev download page states -- alternatively, use LiClipse: http://www.liclipse.com/ -- it's a commercial product but it does make the install process painless for a version of Eclipse which has PyDev (and helps supporting the continued development of PyDev).